# Define Pandas DataFrame as composite boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do this:

```
data['thing'] = data['a'] > 0.75 and data['b'] > 0.5
```

I can do this:

```
dummy_1 = data['a'] > 0.75
```

And I can do this:

```
dummy_2 = data['b'] > 0.5
```

But I can't and them.

Is there an elegant way that people handle this?

(Python 2.7.6, Pandas 0.13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use a boolean and condition (and the parens are important)

docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
data['thing'] = (data['a'] > 0.75) & (data['b'] > 0.5)
```